# How to perform a function based on surrounding cells in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

My rows on my spreadsheet look like the following:

```
foo | cherry | 400
bar | lemon  | 300
foo | cherry | 500
bar | cherry | 70
```

I want another row to make calculations in column C based on the information in columns A and B. For example, I may want an average of all of the values in cells next to "foo", or the sum of all the "cherry" values.

Comment: Check out [pivot tables](http://superuser.com/tags/pivot-table/info). You should be able to get everything you need from one.

Comment: Agreed. Pivot tables are the way to go. Check out [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-or-delete-a-pivottable-or-pivotchart-report-HP010089893.aspx#_Toc263767342) and [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/pivottbls/create2010.php) for somewhere to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you want only these fairly simple calculations,
you can use the `AVERAGEIFS`, `COUNTIFS`, and `SUMIFS` functions. 
`COUNTIFS` simply counts the cells in a range that meet specified criteria. 
For example,

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A5, "foo")
```

returns the number of occurrences of `foo` in column A. 
(This can be expanded to test multiple conditions, including `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=` for numbers.) 
`SUMIFS` *adds* (sums) cells
where other cell(s) in the same row (or column) meet specified criteria. 
For example,

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C5, B2:B5, "cherry")
```

adds the values in column C that correspond to `cherry` in column B. 
`AVERAGEIFS` works the same way, so your first problem can be done as

```
=AVERAGEIFS(C2:C5, A2:A5, "foo")
```

or you can just divide the sum by the count.

There are also `AVERAGEIF`, `COUNTIF`, and `SUMIF` functions that do essentially the same thing,
but they don’t support multiple criteria, and their calling sequences are incompatible.